# How can I pass data between two views, Swift UI / Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to pass a few variables between one view where you set them (configView) to personalView where they can be read and changed.

I've made a new app to simplify and rewrite some messy code, so it's fairly simple now.

personalView

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct personalView: View {
    @Binding var initNum: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("Personal")
        Text(initNum)
    }
}

struct personalView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        personalView()
    }
}
```

configView

```
//  configView.swift


import SwiftUI
import Combine
struct configView: View {
    private enum Field: Int, CaseIterable {
        case initNum, playerNum
    }
    
    @State var playerNum: Int = 1
    @State var initNum: Int = 1

    @FocusState private var focusedField: Field?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        TextField("S", value: $initNum, formatter: NumberFormatter()
                            )
                            .padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
                                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                                    .font(.system(size:40))
                                .frame(width: 60)
                                .focused($focusedField, equals: .initNum)
                       
                        Text("Starting Card")
                                .font(.system(size:40))
                    }
                    HStack {
                        TextField("P", value: $playerNum, formatter: NumberFormatter()
                            )
                            .padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
                                    .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                                    .font(.system(size:40))
                                .frame(width: 60)
                                .focused($focusedField, equals: .playerNum)
                        .toolbar {
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                                Button("Done") {
                                    focusedField = nil
                                    
                                }
                            }
                    }
                        Text("Players")
                                .font(.system(size:40))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }



struct configView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        configView()
    }
}
```

I've tried looking at other Stack Overflow posts, but keep getting errors due to it being an Int and not a string.

Comment: You should create a model in top view or app with the variables you want to edit. Then pass this model as environment object to the view (hierarchies) where you want to use or modify them.

Comment: `Text(initNum, format: .number)` which will format the int as a string and take care of localisation. And btw if you have a `View` that is not writing like this one is currently, then it would just be `let initNum: Int` and not `@Binding var`.

Answer (score 1):

As someone suggested that @EnvironmentObject can be a good choice, specially if you plan to access the data/config in deeply nested views.

Also make sure that your view names are using the proper convention. No camel casing for the structs/classes in Swift.

```
class UserConfig: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userId: Int?
}

struct ConfigView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var userConfig: UserConfig
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Assign Id") {
                userConfig.userId = 12 // assign some id
            }
        }
    }
}


struct PersonalView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var userConfig: UserConfig
    
    var body: some View {
        if let userId = userConfig.userId {
            Text("\(userId)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
          Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(UserConfig())
    }
}
```